# How to convert default binutils into binutils-2.26?

Tags: ubuntu, binutils

When I command "make", then I got an error like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../lib//liblmi.a(LMInterface.o): unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in section `.text'
```

This error is caused by earlier version of binutils, and I have binutils like this:

```
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
```

I installed binutils-2.26 by following commands

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install binutils-2.26
```

But I have a problem, I installed binutils-2.26, but the default binutils version is 2.24, so How can I convert binutils-2.26 into the default binutils?

Comment: `$ dpkg -l | grep binutils`  ==> `ii  binutils                                  2.24-5ubuntu14.2                                    amd64        GNU assembler, linker and binary utilities
ii  binutils-2.26                             2.26.1-1ubuntu1~14.04                               amd64        GNU assembler, linker and binary utilities`

Comment: I just installed binutils by `sudo apt-get install binutils-2.26`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`binutils-2.26` provides the individual programs under names such as `/usr/bin/as-2.26` and `/usr/bin/ld-2.26`, so that the `binutils` and `binutils-2.26` packages can be installed at the same time.  However, unversioned names of the programs are available in the `/usr/lib/binutils-2.26/bin` directory, so you can activate them using this shell command:

```
PATH="/usr/lib/binutils-2.26/bin:$PATH"
```

As a result, `gcc` and `g++` will use binutils 2.26 instead of the default binutils version.

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved the problem. But there's another problem when I command `make` compile: `block_builder.cc:(.text+0x29e): undefined reference to std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long)'`, My ubuntu version is 14.04, so is this caused by version of ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, you need a newer `libstdc++`, or compile with something like DTS for Ubuntu (not sure if that actually exists, sorry).

Comment: So how can i get newer `libstdc++`? Is there other ways except upgrading Ubuntu? I add command like this : `CFLAGS= -c -O2 -Wall -D_I386 -D_UNIX -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -std=c++11 -Wno-sign-compare -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`, But the result does not change...

Comment: And the version of `libstdc++` is `libstdc++.so.6`