# how does "make" determine which linker to use?

Tags: makefile, linker, ubuntu-14.04, binutils

I wanted to upgrade to  binutils 2.26 , so i followed the steps here : [How to convert default binutils into binutils-2.26?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52754728/how-to-convert-default-binutils-into-binutils-2-26) to solve the same "unrecognized relocation" error.

Now my default linker is 2.26

```
$ ld --version


GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

But "make" still uses the "/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld" (which is 2.24) and still gives the same error.

So how to force "make" to use the default linker ?

Comment: You'll better upgrade your entire distribution. Ubuntu 14 is ancient. So upgrade to the current [Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch you are write , But i wanted to understand why is "make" not choosing the default linker

Comment: Because it is not `make` which chooses it. See my answer.

Comment: The very short answer is, make doesn't choose it.  Make invokes a shell and tells it to run whatever commands you've provided in the recipe for the rule (indented by TAB characters).  It has no idea what those commands do or how they do it... it's _identical_ to you typing that command into a shell prompt and hitting ENTER.  Since you haven't shown us what commands those are (make will print them out before it runs them, unless you've suppressed its output), there's little else we can say about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon your `Makefile` (which you could debug with [`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) `-x`). Notice that `make` has a lot of builtin rules. Use `make -p` to also print them. Notice the rules mentioning `LINK.c` or `LINK.cc` etc, and notice that `LD` is not much used. Notice also that `ld` is almost never used directly (most of the time, some other program like `gcc` or `g++` runs it).

And it is also a matter of the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). So try setting it so that your new `ld` comes before the old one.

Generally, you link with the `gcc` or `g++` program (so it is [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) which matters, not `make`; read about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) and [its `-fuse-ld=`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)), and that `gcc` or `g++` will run the linker (you might, but I don't recommend to, change its [spec file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) which governs what actual programs are run by `gcc` or `g++` which are only *drivers* to other programs such as `cc1`, `as`, `ld`, [`collect2`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html) etc...). To understand what programs `gcc` or `g++` is running, pass it the [`-v` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html).

> But "make" still uses the "/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld" (which is 2.24) and still gives the same error.

On my Debian system `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld` (it is generally started by `gcc`, not directly by `make`) is a symlink. You might (but I don't recommend that) just change that symlink.

---

BTW, you are using an ancient Ubuntu 14. **You'll better upgrade your entire distribution** (e.g. to [Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) at end of 2018), because there is not only `ld` but many other programs which are really old on your system.

Upgrading your distribution will take less time than upgrading, compiling, installing and configuring each individual tool.

Comment: for the PATH variable, I did exactly what said. And noticed the change in the default `ld` , I can delete this linker and then it will use my new default. But i think that is not right. It seems strange that `make` doesn't use the default linker

Comment: As I am explaining, it is `gcc` which chooses a linker in practice. Very probably, your `make` *never* runs `ld` directly.

Comment: you are right , when i tried `gcc -v` I can see `--with-ld=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld`. not sure how to change it to chose the default, But I think this answers my question in the most part.

Comment: As I answered, if you want to choose that permanently, you'll change or add a `spec` file. But you really should update your entire distribution